# Java calling details from array list from another class

Tags: java, arrays, serialization, arraylist

i have 2 sample classes to try and understand array lists better. PersonData contains an array list. PersonType is going to get the details from the array list. i'm trying to understand the logic behind an array list. if the user is asked to enter a personID for example, how could i bring back that person's Letter and Age. how can i retrieve 1 persons contents from the array list by entering in a value from their list?

```
public class PersonData {

    private final List<personList> personList;

    public PersonData() {  //constructor
        personList= new ArrayList<>();
        personList.add(new personList(1, 'x', 23));
        personList.add(new personList(2, 'y', 28));
        personList.add(new personList(3, 'z', 37));

    }
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class PersonType implements Serializable {

    int personID;
    String personLetter;
    int personAge;

    // constructor 
    public PersonType (int pID, String pLetter, int pAge) {
        personID= pID;
        personLetter = pLetter;
        personAge= pAge;
    }

    public PersonType () {
        this(0,"",0);
    }

    public int getPersonID() {
        return (personID);
    }

    public String getPersonLetter() {
        return (personLetter );
    }

    public int getPersonAge() {
        return (personAge);
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `new PersonType`? Please only post code that compiles (MCVE).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use a Map instead of a List.

```
public class PersonData {

  private final Map<Integer,PersonType> map;

  public PersonData() {  //constructor
    map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put( 1, new PersonType(1, 'x', 23));
    map.put( 2, new PersonType(2, 'y', 28));
    map.put( 3, new PersonType(3, 'z', 37));
 }
```

Now you can get a particular person by ID, in constant time.

```
 PersonType person = map.get( 2 );
```

If you really want to store the data in a list, then finding a particular match can require a linear search through the list. (If you know it's sorted, you could do a binary search, for an O(log n) cost.)

Here's a sketch of a linear search through the list for the first matching element. (I don't have a compiler in front of me.) Given:

```
private final List<personList> personList;
```

Then to find a person in the list with a matching ID:

```
int searchID = 2;

Optional<PersonType> p = personList.stream()
  .filter( p -> p.getPersonID() == searchID )
  .findFirst();
```

Comment: so there's no way array lists can do this?

Comment: Yes, you can do it with lists, but accessing the right element will be more work, both for you and the virtual machine. I'll try to sketch out an approach with streams. I'm away from my desk at the moment, so bear in mind that it's not been tested.

Comment: A `List<V>` is, conceptually, very similar to a `Map<Integer, V>`. You often *can* use a `List` as you're describing. But it's not generally a good idea - `Map` implementations are generally much more efficient for lookup-style operations. The exception is if your keys are always going to be consecutive positive integers (preferably starting from zero). In that limited case a `List` may be preferable.

Comment: @userlml - Okay, I sketched out an approach for lists. Bear in mind that with a list, the cost of accessing an element by ID grows linearly with the number of elements in the list. With a HashMap, it stays constant.

Comment: Also if person ids are within a short range you can use ArrayList directly and store/access object based on the index (List.get() method) which can act as  an Id